# Can not select an item from WinList in codedui

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am doing automation for a desktop winform application and I want to select from a combobox , I dont know why but is recognized as a WinList instead of a standard combobox. codedui opens the list by clicking the button near it but can not select an item, getting error for it.
Here is the recorded code for the UI element

```
        WinButton uIOpenButton = this.UIProMANAGEWindow.UIProductionReportWindow.UICbReportComboBox.UIOpenButton;
        WinList uIItemList = this.UIItemWindow.UIItemClient.UIItemList;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Open' button
        Mouse.Click(uIOpenButton, new Point(9, 9));

        // Select '' in list box
        uIItemList.SelectedItemsAsString = this.URFSelectReportParams.UIItemListSelectedItemsAsString;
```

Here is the exception I am getting

```
Message: Test method CodedUITestProject2.Raporlar_URF1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnBlockedControlException: Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked control visible and retry the action. Additional Details: TechnologyName:  'MSAA'ControlType:  'List' ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0xF004F003
```

Comment: Did you check the draworder for that control in the application under test?
Also, I suspect those WinList items got marked as invisible when your test was loaded and that it did not change that property to visible once that 'Open' button got clicked. You can force your test to reload that WinList once the combobox is opened. Take a look at the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848757/how-to-refresh-uimap-object-in-codedui) question.

Answer (score 1):

After the `WinList` opens ,you need to check the properties of the control that opens. It might most certainly be `Wincustom` and in it there would be `WinListItem`.
You have to create these controls and then click the `Winlistitem` you want using `Mouse.Click()`.

Comment: Selecting item doesnt help. I solve the issue by directly writing item on the list (by using SendKeys)