# UIAComWrapper failing to return child nodes of WPF control that was previously COLLAPSED

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-ui-automation

I am attempting to create Coded UI tests on a WPF application.  I am using Visual Studio 2019 to create / run the tests.

I am running into a strange behavior where a WPF button that was collapsed at startup (but is later made visible/enabled) is not showing any child nodes using any of the FindXXX methods available to the AutomationElement object associated with the button.  Other buttons that were not collapsed do not seem to have this problem.  I should note that the reason I am expecting child nodes for this WPF button is that in the XAML it is defined similar to the following:

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonStop" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding TheVm.StopCommand}">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyleA}">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TheVm.DisplayButton}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
  <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ControlsStackPanelStyle}">
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Assets/icon1.png" Style="{StaticResource ControlsButtonImageStyle}"/>
    <ContentPresenter Content="Stop" Style="{StaticResource ControlsButtonTextStyle}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Using the INSPECT.EXE application I can see the child nodes of this button correctly, but when I traverse the AutomationElements I have access to they are missing.

The test code I am using to check the human-readable text is:

```
// Wait for 'Stop' button to become enabled, and verify correct text
uIButtonStopButton.WaitForControlEnabled();         
var displayText = (!uIButtonStopButton.DisplayText.Equals(""))
                   ? uIButtonStopButton.DisplayText 
                   : GetFirstNodeText(uIButtonStopButton.NativeElement as AutomationElement;
Assert.AreEqual("Stop", displayText, "Stop button doesn\'t have correct text.");
```

Where the GetFirstNodeText method is as follows:

```
private static string GetFirstNodeText(AutomationElement automationElement)
{
  if (automationElement != null)
  {
    // Get first AutomationElement node that is a 'text' control-type
    var textEl = automationElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "text"));
    if (textEl != null) return textEl.Current.Name;
  }
  return "";
}
```

An additional (interesting) piece of information: I tried a similar test using Appium/WinAppDriver and had an almost identical experience - no child nodes on the formerly collapsed button.

What could be causing this and do you have any advice for this?

Comment: Maybe try reloading the element that got disabled?
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848757/how-to-refresh-uimap-object-in-codedui) question. It's about the UIMap, but should apply to any `UITestControl`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to add the following line of code:  "uiButtonStopButton.Find();" before the call to get the DisplayText and it didn't seem to have any effect. I also added SearchAlways to the StopButton in UIMap.uitest also with no effect.

Comment: I have also tried setting the WpfButton (uIButtonStopButton) to null and forcing a new instance of it - same result.

Comment: I'm starting to think the problem could be in the application under test, since you mentioned the problem is also seen when using WinAppDriver. If you have access to the application source code, maybe try reloading the button from there. Do the child nodes show up in your test script if you first make a call to them in the application under test? It could make sense that the children did not load because of the fact the parent was collapsed at startup, but I'm not sure if it works that way.

Comment: I do have access to the app under test, and you are definitely correct.  Another developer just modified the XAML and the behavior was corrected.  When I understand what was causing the initial problem in the XAML, I will update this question with the details.

Comment: The XAML changes that 'fixed' the problem seem to be binding related (though to be honest, I am a bit perplexed why the original code works from the user's perspective, but not UIA).  The DataContext was changed to a more specific class, and a data template / selection used.  I suspect that there was an underlying property notification that somehow didn't propagate up in the way UIA was expecting it to, but updated the UI in an acceptable fashion.  Sorry about the non-specific description - but you were correct about it being an application issue. I will give you the answer if you post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify your are working with up-to-date `AutomationElement` objects, be sure to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848757/how-to-refresh-uimap-object-in-codedui) question about refreshing your controls.

But since you mentioned having a almost identical problem using WinAppDriver, I rather think the problem will be with the application under test.
If you have access to the source code / developers working on that code, please take a closer look to the code/xaml involving this button and its children. The problem will most likely be found there.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  My application had a binding / property change notification problem, and it was not a problem with UIA at all.

Comment: No problem at all, glad I could help. Sometimes a problem is more clear to people outside a project because it can be looked upon "from a distance".